# Is it possible to get a cookie from an app?

Tags: android, session-cookies

I want to know that , Is it possible that we can access cookies from an app (android) for example - Currently i am logged in , in amazon videos . I want to access cookies (json id) or particularly like this:-

```
[
{
"domain": ".primevideo.com",
"expirationDate": 2183886856,
"hostOnly": false,
"httpOnly": true,
"name": "at-main-av",
"path": "/",
"sameSite": "no_restriction",
"secure": true,
"session": false,
"storeId": "0",
"value": "Atza|IwEBII7su3R9CsArd2BfylvT5To5LaOLd2gFKOn23APyjsGwk2ieHxH4PXzpHiZSRDXAJJEpRrE-RzYYFFAsLMKthk9ZX3SJ1WEWFzwxPEOhAGZiQO_e5x-sTNRyLbM8cJZZkBX6z738zkb0XLWGUFbY6Ny0Ls0ll9CcpgnhF9DAaHuibw7M9qBGdeNHREkEe2lrqoKu8xk1HbQbjMS59H43okkqRFtifAMmk4HNINlAPwJ7XooorOlZ9Nw48xgzd_m5j4yVz59nFCsUvGh9XF3DJjQidagWXnLTj2zSOYeLNdSu6ChedMo6CdQtXOGJN7vwfQMPT_A0L3KzXt_h38YRn8zDAz-y-r2TEzWV86FxmkZGycI2BeQhYZ6sDEG_7RwRwGpVtd33dCB1C6GMim5cXD4pluwO0BU3-N-kL1VqHP9FhnxFhvKuK4xQi72Mt4_YVcs",
"id": 1
  }
]
```

Comment: Does Android looks like a jar? No, you can't, unless you have a rooted phone.

Comment: If i have rooted phone then what i have to do ???

Comment: I suggest against doing that. You could rather create an app which contains a webview, then log in using that webview and extract the cookies by code. Hacking into chrome with some rooted commands will probably not be easy since you will be using undocumented features

Comment: I am simply asking that , is it possible that we get cookie from android login app. Yes or no ( app may be of amazon , flipkart , or any.... )